# Why PhpStorm method autocompete isn't working?

Tags: wordpress, docker, autocomplete, phpstorm

I have a plain PHP (not OO) and when I create a function, PhpStorm autocomplete doesn't know about it.

I can <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> to jump into the method but no autocomplete.

I don't understand why such a basic thing isn't working so maybe I'm missing some settings?

My project is a WordPress on a local Docker setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure a PHP interpreter. In in my case I had to point to my Docker PHP container because that's where my code lives and PHPStorm will evaluate things in the same PHP version as the one in your container.

Configure PHP interpreter:

- Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP
- Configure CLI interpreter by clicking ...
- Click +
- Choose Docker or Docker Compose > point to your PHP container > OK

Check that your mapping is correct. I have an Apache container and the mapping looks like this:

`<Project root>/src => /var/www/html`

EDIT:

I also noticed autocomplete doesn't work if you mark the directory as 'excluded' in PhpStorm.

And final note: I did 'Invalidate cache and restart'.

Now I'm totally not sure what did the trick :D